# How to extract specific data from many csv files and place into a new single csv in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a directory with about 3000 or 4000 csv files, all with the same basic format (changed to simple numbers and headers for simplicity's sake):

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J     # header
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0     # let's call this line X
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9     # let's call this line Y
```

I would like to create one master csv file containing specific information from all of the original ones, with the header following this format: `filename,XI,YB,XB,YB-XB`.

To continue the previous example, this is what the header and first line of the new csv file would ideally look like:

```
filename,XI,YB,XB,YB-XB
File1,9,1,2,-1
File2,...
```

... and so on, to create a master csv file that contains the same specific information from every original csv in the directory.

I'm new to python and have tried writing a code that will do this for me, but this is more complicated than the small amount of practice I've had before. Any help to explain how to do this or examples of code would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Erin

Edit: 
After looking online to see if I could find if there have already been an answer to this question, I was able to piece together most of a working code that accomplishes what I want it to do, although I am still unable to access the specific numbers in the original csv files. Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
import glob
import os

outfile = open('path/output.csv', 'w') 
outfile.write('filename,XI,YB,XB,YB-XB\n') 
for filename in glob.glob('path/*.csv'): 
    if filename == 'output.csv':
        continue     # to skip this file 
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile: 
        count = 0
        lineno = 0 
        for lineno == 1: 
            continue     # skips header
        fields = line.split(',') 
        a =     # Here goes the code to access XI
        b =     # Here goes the code to access YB 
        c =     # Here goes the code to access XB
        d = b - c 
        outfile.write('%s,%g,%g,%g,%g\n' % (filename, a, b, c, d)) 
        count += 1
    if count == 0:     # in case of empty files
        outfile.write('%s,0,0,0,0\n' % filename) 
        print '%s is empty!' % filename
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Paste your code!

Comment: Indeed! Share what you've tried and maybe how you think you could solve it!

Comment: The code I have up to this point has been added now.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done with pandas in the following way if all files have same column names

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

df_all = pd.DataFrame(columns =['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume'] )

for filename in glob.glob('path\*.csv'): 
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,usecols = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume'])
    df_all = pd.concat([df,df_all],axis=0)

df_all.to_csv(mergedfilename)
```

Comment: Edited for specific columns